# Using both picker input and date range input on a single graph on shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to use both picker input and date range input on a single graph. Initially i used picker input to select different locations for my data and it worked, the code is as below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(shinyWidgets)


mydata<- "x  Group.2 Group.1
32.93000 1984-05-22      Chololo
13.44500 1984-07-18      Chololo
14.41667 1984-10-19      Chololo
10.53000 1984-10-29 West.Reserve
22.96750 1984-11-17      Chololo
38.75000 1984-12-05      Chololo
29.58000 1985-01-14      Chololo
30.64000 1985-01-14 West.Reserve
22.70000 1985-01-25 East.Reserve
40.69000 1985-01-25 West.Reserve
16.17667 1985-03-16      Chololo
15.82000 1985-03-16 East.Reserve
34.34000 1985-03-16 West.Reserve
101.53000 1985-05-25 West.Reserve
74.55000 1985-05-26      Chololo
73.49000 1985-05-26 East.Reserve
44.12500 1985-09-05      Chololo
31.43000 1985-09-05 East.Reserve
79.84000 1985-09-05 West.Reserve
22.70000 1985-12-02      Chololo
19.53000 1985-12-02 East.Reserve
34.34000 1985-12-02 West.Reserve
27.25000 1986-01-17 West.Reserve
20.85000 1986-01-30      Chololo
13.18000 1986-01-30 East.Reserve
36.99000 1986-01-30 West.Reserve
15.29500 1986-03-15      Chololo
8.95000 1986-03-15 East.Reserve
19.00000 1986-03-15 West.Reserve
15.56500 1986-04-27      Chololo
13.97500 1986-04-27 East.Reserve
28.52000 1986-04-27 West.Reserve
47.83500 1986-06-16      Chololo
102.90000 1986-06-16 East.Reserve
119.53000 1986-06-16 West.Reserve
82.22000 1986-07-31      Chololo
88.57000 1986-07-31 East.Reserve
95.71000 1986-07-31 West.Reserve
57.88500 1986-09-20      Chololo
45.19000 1986-09-20 East.Reserve"

Data <- read.table(text=mydata, header = TRUE)
Data$Group.2<-as.POSIXct(Data$Group.2,format="%Y-%m-%d")


ui<-shinyUI(
  dashboardPage(skin="red",
              dashboardHeader(title = "Biomass"),  
              dashboardSidebar(id="", width=260, sidebarMenuOutput("sidemenu")),
              dashboardBody(
                tabItems(
                  tabItem(tabName = "Biomass",
                          fluidRow(HTML("<br/>"),
                                   box(width=6, pickerInput("Locations","Select a location:", choices=c("Chololo","Doldol", "East.Reserve", "West.Reserve"),selected = c("Chololo"),options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),multiple = T)),
                                   box(width= 6, dateRangeInput(inputId = "daterange2", label = "Select the date range:", start = min(Data$Group.2), end = max(Data$Group.2), min = min(Data$Group.2), max = max(Data$Group.2), format = "yyyy/mm/dd", separator = "/"))),
                          fluidRow(
                            box(width = 10, title=" Biomass: Selected location ", background ="blue", plotlyOutput("plot1"), collapsible = TRUE))
                          )
                )
              )

                )

)

Server<- shinyServer(function(input,output, session){
  output$sidemenu<-renderMenu({
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Biomass Data", tabName = "Biomass", icon = icon("chart-line"),selected = TRUE)
    )
  })

  myfilter <- reactive({subset(Data,Data$Group.1 %in% input$Locations|Data, Data$Group.2>=as.POSIXct(input$daterange2[1])& Data$Group.2 <=as.POSIXct(input$daterange2[2]))})

  output$plot1<-renderPlotly({


    p<-ggplot(data= myfilter(),aes(x=myfilter()[,2], y=myfilter()[,1]))+geom_line()+theme_bw()+theme(axis.title = element_text(face="plain", size=20), plot.title = element_text(face="plain",size=25),axis.text=element_text(face="plain",size=20),legend.text=element_text(size=16),legend.title=element_text(size=20))+
      xlab("Year")+ylab("Biomass g/sqm")+ ylim(0,200)
    pp<-ggplotly(p)
    pp
  })

  })

shinyApp(ui=ui, server = Server)
```

The problem comes in when i try to add the daterange input to the reactive function so that both the location and the date can be selected at the same time. I am quite a newbie in r so if i asked an obvious question or i am not clear enough please tell me.

I tried adding the subset for the daterange input to this line

```
myfilter <- reactive({subset(Data,Data$Group.1 %in% input$Locations)})
```

like so

```
  myfilter <- reactive({subset(Data,Data$Group.1 %in% input$Locations|Data, Data$Group.2>=as.POSIXct(input$daterange2[1])& Data$Group.2 <=as.POSIXct(input$daterange2[2]))})
```

but i get this error "Warning: Error in Ops.POSIXt: '|' not defined for "POSIXt" objects"

I tried looking at other questions on here but i can't seem to find a similar question.
What i did is probably inaccurate so if i could get any ideas on how i can make the graph react to both the picker input and the date range input i will be grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look the the tidyverse and especially dplyr. Makes it much easier :-).

Updated the code, so when you unselected all countries, you will not get an error message, but a nice warning.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)

mydata<- "x  Group.2 Group.1
32.93000 1984-05-22      Chololo
13.44500 1984-07-18      Chololo
14.41667 1984-10-19      Chololo
10.53000 1984-10-29 West.Reserve
22.96750 1984-11-17      Chololo
38.75000 1984-12-05      Chololo
29.58000 1985-01-14      Chololo
30.64000 1985-01-14 West.Reserve
22.70000 1985-01-25 East.Reserve
40.69000 1985-01-25 West.Reserve
16.17667 1985-03-16      Chololo
15.82000 1985-03-16 East.Reserve
34.34000 1985-03-16 West.Reserve
101.53000 1985-05-25 West.Reserve
74.55000 1985-05-26      Chololo
73.49000 1985-05-26 East.Reserve
44.12500 1985-09-05      Chololo
31.43000 1985-09-05 East.Reserve
79.84000 1985-09-05 West.Reserve
22.70000 1985-12-02      Chololo
19.53000 1985-12-02 East.Reserve
34.34000 1985-12-02 West.Reserve
27.25000 1986-01-17 West.Reserve
20.85000 1986-01-30      Chololo
13.18000 1986-01-30 East.Reserve
36.99000 1986-01-30 West.Reserve
15.29500 1986-03-15      Chololo
8.95000 1986-03-15 East.Reserve
19.00000 1986-03-15 West.Reserve
15.56500 1986-04-27      Chololo
13.97500 1986-04-27 East.Reserve
28.52000 1986-04-27 West.Reserve
47.83500 1986-06-16      Chololo
102.90000 1986-06-16 East.Reserve
119.53000 1986-06-16 West.Reserve
82.22000 1986-07-31      Chololo
88.57000 1986-07-31 East.Reserve
95.71000 1986-07-31 West.Reserve
57.88500 1986-09-20      Chololo
45.19000 1986-09-20 East.Reserve"

Data <- read.table(text=mydata, header = TRUE)
Data$Group.2<-as.POSIXct(Data$Group.2,format="%Y-%m-%d")


ui<-shinyUI(
    dashboardPage(skin="red",
                  dashboardHeader(title = "Biomass"),  
                  dashboardSidebar(id="", width=260, sidebarMenuOutput("sidemenu")),
                  dashboardBody(
                      tabItems(
                          tabItem(tabName = "Biomass",
                                  fluidRow(HTML("<br/>"),
                                           box(width=6, pickerInput("Locations","Select a location:", choices=c("Chololo","Doldol", "East.Reserve", "West.Reserve"),selected = c("Chololo"),options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),multiple = T)),
                                           box(width= 6, dateRangeInput(inputId = "daterange2", label = "Select the date range:", start = min(Data$Group.2), end = max(Data$Group.2), min = min(Data$Group.2), max = max(Data$Group.2), format = "yyyy/mm/dd", separator = "/"))),
                                  fluidRow(
                                      box(width = 10, title=" Biomass: Selected location ", background ="blue", uiOutput("plot1"), collapsible = TRUE))
                          )
                      )
                  )

    )

)

Server<- shinyServer(function(input,output, session){
    output$sidemenu<-renderMenu({
        sidebarMenu(
            menuItem("Biomass Data", tabName = "Biomass", icon = icon("chart-line"),selected = TRUE)
        )
    })

    myfilter <- reactive({

        result <- Data %>%
            dplyr::filter(Group.1 %in% input$Locations & (Group.2>=as.POSIXct(input$daterange2[1]) & Group.2 <=as.POSIXct(input$daterange2[2])))
        print(result)
        result
        })


    output$plot1 <- renderUI({
        if(nrow(myfilter()) == 0) {
            return(
                HTML("No data selected. Please choose at least one location.")
            )
        } else {

            output$plot<-renderPlotly({


                p<-ggplot(data= myfilter(),aes(x=myfilter()[,2], y=myfilter()[,1]))+geom_line()+theme_bw()+theme(axis.title = element_text(face="plain", size=20), plot.title = element_text(face="plain",size=25),axis.text=element_text(face="plain",size=20),legend.text=element_text(size=16),legend.title=element_text(size=20))+
                    xlab("Year")+ylab("Biomass g/sqm")+ ylim(0,200)
                pp<-ggplotly(p)
                pp
            })

            plotlyOutput("plot")

        }
    })



})

shinyApp(ui=ui, server = Server)
```

Comment: thanks that is sort of what i want but i think it's filtering the data  instead of removing the unwanted dates completely, like when i select from 1985 to 1986, the biomass values for the 1984 dates are still visible. and for some reason it's selecting all the data when i select one location. is it possible to have a single location's  data and a specific date range say 1985-1986 visible on the dashboard only?

Comment: Yes, but you need a different operator then. & instead of |. What you did before was that the location had to be the selected OR has to be inside the data range. This means, you had dates for the locations which were selected in the location dropdown. If my answer helped you, please accept it :-)

Comment: Also used `renderUI` in combination with plotly now. This is always a good way to render stuff that may fail to render if for examples filter are selected in way that there is no data to render the plot.

Comment: Thank you so much, adding renderUI did the trick I think, thanks:-)